# Java: count of digits in String using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am studying regexes and wanted to know how to check if a string contains a precise amount of number characters inside despite the fact that they may be divided but other kinds of characters.

Here I have the method that checks if string follows those parameters:

1)if string starts with '+', then this string has to have precisely 12 number

2)if string starts with '(' or number, then string has to have precisely 10 numbers

3)string may contain 0-2 '-' characters that can't go one after another Example: '--'

4)string may contain 1 pair of brackets '(' and ')', but it is located on the left from '-'

5)brackets has to have 3 numbers in between

6)string does not contain non-number characters inside

7)string ends with number

Here is the method itself:

```
public static boolean checkTelNumber(String number) {
        if (number.matches("\\d{12} | \\d{10}"))
            return number.matches("^\\+?(\\d*(\\(\\d{3}\\))?\\d*(\\-?\\d+\\-?)?\\d*)");
        else return false;
}
```

This method correctly checks for everything except if a string has 10/12 numbers inside if you remove `if (number.matches("\\d{12} | \\d{10}"))` part of it. Thanks in advance!

All my output:

method output | number of the result | actual result | number I used to check

```
true - 1 true +380501234567
true - 2 true +38050123-45-67
true - 3 true +38050123-4567
true - 4 true +3805012345-67
true - 5 true +38(050)1234567
true - 6 true +38(050)123-45-67
true - 7 true +38(050)12345-67
true - 8 true +38(050)123-4567
true - 9 true +-313450531202
true - 10 true +38051202(345)7
true - 11 true +38051202(345)-7
false - 12 false +38050)1234567
false - 13 false +38050)123-45-67
false - 14 false +38050)123-4567
false - 15 false +38050)12345-67
false - 16 false +38(0501234567
false - 17 false +38(050123-45-67
false - 18 false +38(05012345-67
false - 19 false +38(050123-4567
true - 20 false +38(050)12-3456
true - 21 false +38(050)123456
true - 22 false +38(050)12345-6
true - 23 false +38(050)1-23456
false - 24 false +38)050(1234567
false - 25 false +38(050)1-23-45-6-7
false - 26 false +38-(050)1234567
false - 27 false +38((050)1234567
false - 28 false +5(0--5)1234567
false - 29 false +-313450531202))
false - 30 false +38051202(345)-7))
true - 1 true 050123-4567
true - 2 true 050123-45-67
true - 3 true 05012345-67
true - 4 true (999)1112222
true - 5 true (999)111-22-22
true - 6 true (999)111-2222
true - 7 true (999)11122-22
true - 8 true 1-23456789-0
true - 9 true (345)0512027
false - 10 false (345)0512027))
false - 11 false 1-23456789-0))
false - 12 false 7-4-4123689-5
false - 13 false 050ххх4567
true - 14 false 050123456
false - 15 false (0)501234567
```

Comment: Please provide sample correct and incorrect input to help clarify the requirement and make answers easier to verify.

Comment: This doesn't really have a question in it. Is the question "What's a regex that  will match strings that follow parameters 1 - 7?", or is it "What's a regex that matches strings containing exactly 10 (or 12) digits anywhere in a string?"

Comment: All of these rules make the regex hard. A simple loop over the characters would be easier.

Comment: If I had to fix a program with regexes, like the above, all over,  I would probably quit

Comment: I read this 5 times before realizing it's describing a spec for a telephone number.

Comment: break up the logic so if by some miracle, you get it wrong, being able to fix it will take minutes and not hours

Comment: The answer is `^\D*(?:\d\D*){10}^` for precisely 10 digits. What's that other stuff for?

Comment: it is to check if it is a phone number, but the exercise I am doing has those requirements I have to fulfill. Sorry for confustion

Comment: If whoever is teaching you regular expressions gave you a spec like that, I'm impressed you're sticking with it.

Comment: Must this all be done with 1 regular expression? Because while I think it's technically possible, it would be long and unreadable. (Again, in 1 sentence, please clearly state the question you would like us to answer.)

Comment: I got all the requirements matched except the first 2. My question was what do I add to regex in order to check if the number of digits is 10 or 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat tested *not for the feint hearted!!*
Symbiotic validation insures the proper form in the match.

`^(?=\+\D*(?:\d\D*){12}$|(?=[(\d])\D*(?:\d\D*){10}$)(?!.*--)(?!.*-.*\(.*\))(?=[+\d()]*-?[\d()]*-?[\d()]*$)\+?[-\d]*(?:\(\d{3}\))?[-\d]*\d$`

Explained

```
 ^                                          # BOS
 # ASSERTs - Validation
 (?=
      \+                                    # if +, 12 digits
      \D*                      
      (?: \d\D* ){12}
      $ 
   |                                        # or,
      (?= [(\d] )                           # if ( or \d, 10 digits
      \D* 
      (?: \d\D* ){10}
      $ 
 )
 (?! .* -- )                                # optional -, but not 2 in a row

 (?! .* - .* \( .* \) )                     # optional (ddd) but not after -

 (?= [+\d()]* -? [\d()]* -? [\d()]* $ )     # max 2 dashes

 # MATCH
 \+?                                        # optional +
 [-\d]* 
 (?: \( \d{3} \) )?                         # optional (ddd)

 [-\d]*                                     # dash or numbers

 \d                                         # ends with number
 $                                          # EOS
```

Comment: As always, if it answers your question or helps, upvote.

Comment: it worked perfectly, need some time to process and figure out what is what, thanks a lot!